# MySQL passing multiple WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have this query in my mysql database

```
SELECT * FROM tabelXYZ
WHERE ((itemX BETWEEN 240 AND 300)
        AND (ItemY BETWEEN 180 AND 200) 
             AND (ItemZ BETWEEN 70 AND 130))
GROUP BY ItemX ASC
LIMIT 50
```

and I have this 9 results:

```
240 - 195 - 130 
250 - 195 - 130 
255 - 185 - 90 
260 - 195 - 130 
265 - 200 - 125 
270 - 195 - 130 
280 - 195 - 130 
290 - 185 - 100 
300 - 195 - 130
```

my problem is I look for this item

```
240 - 180 - 70
```

I can find this result only if access this query (a small range for itemY, 190 instead of 200)

```
SELECT * FROM tabelXYZ
WHERE ((itemX BETWEEN 240 AND 300)
        AND (ItemY BETWEEN 180 AND 190) 
             AND (ItemZ BETWEEN 70 AND 130))
GROUP BY ItemX ASC
LIMIT 50
```

after this query I recive this result:

```
240 - 180 - 70 
250 - 180 - 70 
255 - 185 - 90 
260 - 180 - 70 
270 - 180 - 70 
280 - 180 - 70 
290 - 185 - 100 
300 - 180 - 70 
240 - 180 - 70
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but I do not know what
because it gives me different results in the first query 
though it should include the results of the second query

I think the mistake arises because the WHERE clause

Comment: Why are you doing `GROUP BY ItemX ASC`? That is "hiding" some rows by grouping them with rows with the same `ItemX`.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your expected output is.

Comment: In other words, what's your expected output? We can explain the results, but we won't be able to provide a solution until you show us what your trying to do. I'll down vote until you improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY ItemX ASC` means it will only return one row per value of `ItemX`.  It may or may not be the row that corresponds to `240 - 180 - 70`.

Comment: In fact, it will be the first row it finds for each group, and if it's not using a unique index, the first row it finds will be arbitrary.

Comment: this was the problem, with ORDER BY itemX ASC, itemY, itemZ, will show all results

Answer (score 0):

If you `GROUP BY ItemX` and say have two items where `itemX = 240` the group clause will select only one of the values and not both.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed up the syntax, this is quite a common mistake, so don't worry.

You will want this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelXYZ
WHERE ((itemX BETWEEN 240 AND 300)
    AND (ItemY BETWEEN 180 AND 200) 
         AND (ItemZ BETWEEN 70 AND 130))
ORDER BY ItemX ASC
LIMIT 50
```

Note that I replaced the `GROUP BY` with an `ORDER BY`. This is all you need to know for now, but you need to keep in mind that `GROUP BY` does something entirely different than grouping.

Comment: thank you, this was the problem - I make this query "ORDER BY lungime ASC, latime, inaltime"

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, remove the group but also your limit and you should see what you are searching for. They are limiting and narrowing, respectively, your result set to the point where you aren't going to see your desired result.